# bad symbolic reference in scala ide for eclipse

Tags: scala, akka, scala-ide

I am trying to compile a Scala / akka  project in scala IDE for eclipse and getting the following errors:

bad symbolic reference to com.typesafe encountered in class file 'ActorSystem.class'. Cannot access term typesafe in package com. The current classpath may be missing a definition for com.typesafe, or ActorSystem.class may have been compiled against a version that's incompatible with the one found on the current classpath.

bad symbolic reference to com.typesafe.config encountered in class file 'ActorSystem.class'. Cannot access term config in value com.typesafe. The current classpath may be missing a definition for com.typesafe.config, or ActorSystem.class may have been compiled against a version that's incompatible with the one found on the current classpath.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

bad symbolic reference means, you are missing some packages in your classpath

For using akka actors you need to added the akka dependency which in turn depends on type safe config. You need to add the following dependencies in your project.

> http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.akka/akka-actor_2.10/2.3.6
>   http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe/config/1.2.1

Use some tools like [sbteclipse](https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse) to generate your eclipse project from your build definition, so that the dependencies are automatically added. Manually downloading the jars separately and adding to project will be a painful process.